# Concurrency of two services that fetch files from one sftp via camel

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concurrency, apache-camel

as said in the title, I have two services and each of them have a camel route inside that downloads files from sftp and processes them according to cron expression(they run at the same time). Problem is that despite of having idempotentConsumer in place, services seems to both take the same file and in logs I can see for example "No such file exception" when one instance was about to move or delete the file. I saw that there are options in camel to lets say lock the file but most of them work only for "file" component and not for sftp. Is there a way to assure that only one instance would processes the file without any errors or warnings? This is my configuration.

```
@Bean
public IdempotentRepository idempotentRepo(final DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcMessageIdRepository idRepository = new JdbcMessageIdRepository(dataSource, PROCESSOR_RESPONSE);
    idRepository.setTableName("SCHEMA.CAMEL_MESSAGEPROCESSED");
    return idRepository;
}
```

And this is the route.

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    from("sftp?preferredAuthentications=password&password=${password}&scheduler=quartz&scheduler.cron=${cron}&useUserKnownHostsFile=false&delete=true&shuffle=true")
            .transacted()
            .idempotentConsumer(header("camelFileAbsolutePath"),
                    idempotentRepository)
            .eager(true)
            .routeId(RouteDownloadResponses.class.getSimpleName())
            .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
            .andSoOn();
}
```

I saw a lot of posts how to set this up either in route option or using this consumer, but I did not find any solution that would work. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems a classic case of producer consumer problem.  See this for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388838/writing-a-program-with-2-threads-which-prints-alternatively/70694332#70694332

Comment: Maybe I do not understand it, but this has nothing to do with threads within one app. I would say there has to be some camel configuration to achieve this and I am missing it.

Comment: See Camel in Action 2nd edition book. It has a chapter on clustering, and this use-case is discussed there, in chapter 12.5.3.

Comment: So I read that using hazelcast repo would be an optimal solution, so my question is. Would this work also for sftp? And would not I achieve something similar using JdbcMessageIdRepository, since both services use the same db?